# How do I set up Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi 3 model B so that it opens with the desktop view?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Just got the Raspberry Pi 3 model B, pre-installed SD card with NOOBS v2.1, have Raspbian on it but can' t work out which option to choose from the boot options in order to have a regular desktop interface?

I have already checked that the SD card is expanded for the OS.

I am new to Raspberry Pi so don't want to pick the wrong options and mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line enter the following command:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

You should now see this:

[image: raspi-config main screen]

then arrow down to option **3 Boot Options** to see the boot options screen.

[image: raspi-config boot options menu]

Then choose either:

**Desktop**

or

**Desktop Autologin**

(Autologin will not prompt you for a username nor password, but does have negative security implications.)

Next click **OK**

and finally

click **Finish**.

You can also access these options via the Raspberry Pi Configuration entry in the Desktop's Preferences Menu.

[image: Preferences Menu]

[image: Boot Options]

You shouldn't worry about a wrong choice here as you can switch between modes relatively easily without problems, by simply rerunning the instructions above and choosing a different option.